# JSON object selector to describe the criteria for querying documents in Azure Cosmos/ Document DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I am using a Javascript Azure function to bind to CosmosDB (Document DB) and query documents within a collection. I would like the `SELECT` query to be formed based on a JSON object that would be coming in the request body. IBM Cloudant provides a feature wherein you can pass a JSON object (selector) to describe the criteria for selecting documents. How do I achieve the same in Azure?

The JSON selector looks like this-

```
{
  "selector": {
  "id": {
          "$gt": 0
        },
  USERS": {
            "username": "Jack",
            "department": "HR"
            }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sql-from-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-from-mongo) npm package provides conversion of expressions similar to these into CosmosDB SQL. The module can be easily loaded in your Azure Functions or it can even be loaded into a sproc with a little bit of manipulation.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the npm package.

Comment: Thanks. I installed your npm package but I am getting an `unexpected token` error at `{sqlFromMongo} = require('sql-from-mongo')`. Any ideas?

Comment: That's CoffeeScript which compiles down to JavaScript like [this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%7BsqlFromMongo%7D%20%3D%20require('sql-from-mongo')).